# Re-wrapping MXF OP1a media into MXF OP-Atom files

Tags: ffmpeg

I have app the records MXF's in OP1a and I need to re-wrap them into OP-Atom files. Is there an FFMpeg command that I can use in terminal that will do this?

I need to batch re-wrap a files and this would help so much.

Thanks!
J

Comment: This is more complicated than it seems, and you're not going to get a satisfactory answer because you're asking 3 questions at once.1) How to re-mux to OP-Atom? The OP-Atom muxer only supports a single "essence" at a time. So each video stream and audio channel has to go into its own MFX file. FFmpeg has no automated method to do this, so each input may need its own custom command which leads to question 2) How to automate export for each essence into individual OP-Atom MXF files?, plus you want to "batch re-wrap" so 3) How to integrate all of this into a bash for loop?

Comment: I can give you an example for a single input if you show info about the input and your ffmpeg. The complete log of `ffmpeg -i input.mxf` will suffice.

Comment: Hmm, I see what you mean. I am new to ffmpeg and to using terminal in this way, I will test and hopefully figure it out. Thank you for the advice and for the blog!